# Bash autorun bash script on USB connect fails to get USB info

Tags: bash, usb, automount

I wrote a script to get all the USB info. So far when I run the script with the USB already connected everything works fine.

```
USB_NAME=$(blkid | grep -oP '(?<=LABEL=").+?(?=")' | tail -1)
USB_DEVICE=$(blkid -o device | tail -1)
USB_TYPE=$(blkid | grep -oP '(?<=TYPE=").+?(?=")' | tail -1)
```

However, when I try to let the autorun script kick by inserting the USB with the `10.usb-rules`:

```
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/home/user/test.sh"
```

It runs the script and everything and i see the output from my script, but the output of my `USB_NAME`, `USB_DEVICE` and `USB_TYPE` all come out blank.

Is it trying to grab the info too quick or something?

Comment: Any error on syslog/journalctl? Could permissions problem.

Comment: Maybe try adding a 5 second sleep before running `blkid` to see if it is a timing thing...

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah... The sleep didn't work. When i run the script manually it works, so something is weird.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz where can I find syslog/journalctl?

Comment: Depending on your distro, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages` or the `journalclt`command.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz You were correct, after adding `sudo` in front of `blkid` on each line, I see output now. When I execute the command as user, it doesn't seem to have permissions issue, do you know what the `user` would be when the `udev usb.rules` runs the script?

Comment: Seems to be root, try `ps -efH | grep udev`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz yes it is root, weird that root couldn't execute those commands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by adding sudo in front of each statement.

```
USB_NAME=$(sudo blkid | grep -oP '(?<=LABEL=").+?(?=")' | tail -1) 2>&1
USB_DEVICE=$(sudo blkid -o device | tail -1) 2>&1
USB_DEVICE_NAME=$(sudo blkid -o device | cut -d'/' -f3 | tail -1) 2>&1
USB_TYPE=$(sudo blkid | grep -oP '(?<=TYPE=").+?(?=")' | tail -1) 2>&1
```